# How can I suspend a light shade from a hanging bulb socket?

Tags: light-fixture

I have this lighting shade that I love, but the fixture to keep it around the socket/bulb is missing. Typically with these types of shades there is a cage that socket can screw into, but I bought the floor model and it is missing that part. The store I bought it from doesn't stock this model anymore (I bought it a while ago for a new house, which is why I didn't realize the part was missing until now).

I can't seem to find a similar part online. Does anyone have any experience making a fixture for these types of shades?

The entry hole is 16cm in diameter with three contact points.

[image: lighting shade with 16 cm hole and three contact points]

[image: lighting socket and bulb]

Comment: I will note that the bulb's socket has been abused, most likely by putting in too high a wattage bulb that's overheated it. It shouldn't be brown like that. For the rest, of the question, it's borderline arts & decorating, as opposed to home improvement...

Comment: Thanks for that. The socket was already installed when I moved in, and it's in a place that's hard to reach so I wasn't going to swap it if I didn't have to. But if it's a safety thing I do have the mount for this lamp to install.

Answer (score 3):

**Three little pieces of wire.**

1. Acquire 36" (1m) #12 or 2mm copper wire, or slightly larger aluminum.
2. Cut it into three equal lengths.
3. Arrange the lengths in a triangle.
4. Begin to twist each pair of ends* to create single arms from the two wires.
5. Stop when the remaining inner triangle is slightly smaller than the bulb socket.
6. Stretch the inner triangle over the socket, then squeeze it back into a triangle so it hangs on the spherical top of the socket.
7. Bend the arms downward in smooth arcs until their spacing matches that of the eyelets in the shade frame. Press them against a can or bottle for nicer curves.
8. Trim the arms to uniform length, then bend upward small outward or sideways hooks on the end of each arm.
9. Hang the shade on the hooks. Optionally pinch them closed.

You'll need to experiment a bit to get width and height right. It's possible I've underestimated wire length, too. Do your own measuring. I'm also guessing at wire gauge. I'm not sure what this thing weighs, and the length and dangle angle of the arms is a factor.

* A good strategy here is to secure the wires in a clamp or vice and use a drill chuck to twist the wires, resulting in a very uniform spiral.

Comment: 1m is about 39.4" not 36".

Comment: Love the attention to detail! I may give this a go tomorrow

Comment: @SolarMike it's a pair of suggestions, not a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

So new bulb holder with the large nuts.

Then get a metal disc with a hole so it can be held by the nuts in the new bulb holder.

Then weld 3 steel wires or rods onto the metal disc and turn the ends up so they go into the 3 holes on the shade.

Comment: Threaded rods should work also without the need for welding.  Three holes in the disk and a few nuts to hold the rods.  For the weight might get away with just hooking the rods to the disk.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this solution. I don't even know what the first sentence (fragment) means. "Get a metal disc with a hole"? How does one do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a clip on lamp shade, no fuss no muss. Search for""clip on lamp shades for hanging lights" you will find a lot at a low cost and even in stock in many variety stores. They simply clip on the bulb. I would replace the socket if you can.

Comment: I'm in Scandinavian, and therefore that search isn't coming up with good results. Parts are harder to come by here than they are in America. But it gives me a new avenue to hunt down.